# SQL - extract multiple values

Tags: sql, delphi-xe2

I have an SQL table with Member ID's.

Each member has information regarding their insurance claims listed in the table.

One column lists insurance ID's in relation to `Member-ID`.

for example:-

```
|Member ID    | Insurance Code   |
----------------------------------
|C#$#@@!1231  | 67               |
```

Now the issue is the same member could have different Insurance Code#'s as a part of previous claims.

For example between 2010 -2011, the member had a claim Code = 67
But for 2011 - 2012, the member had a claim Code = 3

Now when I create a SQL query, I only get one value for claim code.... how can I get all the values, say 67, 3, and 110? Such that I can respond to all claims that the member has been a part of.

```
// SQL QUERY to gather member information.
DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select HPFROMDT, HPthruDt, MEMBERKEY, MEMBHPKEY, OPFROMDT, OPTHRUDT, HPCODEKEY' +
                      ' from MEMBHP' +
                      ' where MEMBERKEY = ''' + MembKey + '''  and OPTHRUDT >= ''' + init_date + ''' and OPFROMDT <= ''' + final_date +''' and OPFROMDT < OPTHRUDT'
                     );

//  Showmessage(DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL[0]);

DMS.ADOQuery1.Open;

// Adding the query values to the appropriate variables.
HPCodeKey := (DMS.ADOQuery1.FieldByNAme('HPCODEKEY').AsString);

DMS.ADOQuery1.Close;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all the records returned by query, not only the first one.
Check also filter dates in SQL statement (where condition).

```
// SQL QUERY to gather member information.
DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select HPFROMDT, HPthruDt, MEMBERKEY, MEMBHPKEY, OPFROMDT,      OPTHRUDT, HPCODEKEY' +
                  ' from MEMBHP' +
                  ' where MEMBERKEY = ''' + MembKey + '''  and OPTHRUDT >= ''' +   init_date + ''' and OPFROMDT <= ''' + final_date +''' and OPFROMDT < OPTHRUDT'
                 );

//  Showmessage(DMS.ADOQuery1.SQL[0]);

DMS.ADOQuery1.Open;

while not DMS.ADOQuery1.Eof do
begin
  // Adding the query values to the appropriate variables.
  Showmessage(DMS.ADOQuery1.FieldByNAme('HPCODEKEY').AsString);
  DMS.ADOQuery1.Next;
end;
DMS.ADOQuery1.Close;
```